# "Computed" key from Sql server scalar functions

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, freetds

I have a project that uses *MSSQL* over pdo_dblib and freetds. MS scalar functions always returned their data in this format:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["computed"]=> string(3) "922" } }.
```

But now, on one of the servers the format suddenly is:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [""]=> string(3) "922" } }.
```

So the key in the array became empty instead of "computed".

I know that I can change that key in my select statements by adding "as" clause. Still, the question is, what controls the default key?

Both servers use the same database.

As far as I know, this "computed" key is something that's added by pdo_dblib.

PHP version is different between servers, the one with computed has old 5.3, while the one with empty key has 5.5. But I think that this server had 5.5 for quite some time, while the computed key disappeared just yesterday. Not 100% sure though...

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found out that this happens because there was a change in [this commit to pdo_dblib](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/3a069e814fe01b36812b5c768dd52ccdea3ed098#diff-7509b5e9cb6dac89cd03a613269952e4). The motivation for this change was that it was clogging up memory.

It should be noted that the version [that you get from pecl](http://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_DBLIB) is weird. It has "computed" in dblib_stmt.c source, but still does not use it.

The version that works, is the one bundled with php sources. I was able to take sources from php-5.3.29\ext\pdo_dblib\ and build them against 5.6.4.